# Professional hunter's decision

Tags: logical-deduction, situation

Assume that you are a professional hunter, roaming in a thick forest about which you have some idea of the layout, though not a thorough one. For example, you remember very well-known landmarks like a steep hill and an ever-flowing river which are located distantly apart. You also vaguely remember that there are lot of flower-bearing plants/trees on the banks of the river.

While hunting game, you get lost in the midst of the forest and you wish to find a way out of it. From your current location, you can see swarms of bees going in two specific directions – towards your left at an average speed of 30 km/h and towards your right at an average speed of 20 km/h.

At this point, you wish to proceed towards the **river** and cross it.

So, as a professional hunter, with the above facts and assumptions available to you, which direction you should choose and why?

Comment: You take out the tracker and hunt the invisible rabbit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Go left. The slower-moving bees are going slower because they are carrying pollen/nectar and are going back to their nest. The faster-moving bees are going to the flowers at the riverbank, so follow them.

Comment: Well, that is really quick, @Jaap Sc...s.

Answer (score 2):

Well, just an idea it might be silly

> Maybe the bees that are going towards right are slower due to 5km/h wind towards left, which also makes other bees 5km/h faster. And since the wind is going from right to left, left side is the low pressure area and most likely to have low altitude, thus left side leads to the river bank.

Comment: Doesn't wind move from areas of high pressure to areas of low pressure?

Comment: Oh for sure, my bad. So the answer for this logic should be vice versa

Comment: Thanks for the input, answer has been changed accordingly.